# System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dll, monodevelop

I am trying to connect my .NT MVC app with the database. THe first page where I am accessing the database is in my Registration page. The thing is that after completing the information in  the form, on submit I keep getting this error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException Unable to load the specified
>   metadata resource. Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
>   Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or
>   object): EntityFramework.

According to other soutions I googled about, I think the issue might be  caused by the code in `Web.config` file. To be specific, I think it is located here:

```
<add name="StudAccommodationEntities1"connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Register.csdl|res://*/Models.Register.ssdl|res://*/Models.Register.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=LAPTOP-JBAK70FS;initial catalog=StudAccommodation;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

But I don't know exactly what and what should I do to fix it. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/troubleshooting-entity-framework-connection-strings-38628

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace of the exception as in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042289/mono-4-5-profile-entity-framework-npgsql-npgsqlsystem-invalidcastexception-ca

Comment: Yes. Here it is: https://coltaemanuela.github.io/FireEdit/?id=stacktrace